# обратный отсчет на сервере с привязкой к БД и выводом на сайт

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp, servlet

Ребята, всем привет, подскажите куда копать или помогите кодом, мне нужен счетчик времени – обратный отчет, и вывод всего этого дела на сайт. Все на Джаве. Конструкция такая клиент на JSP, далее сервлет. Конечная точка времени записана в БД в виде TIMESTAMP в Mysql. То бишь посылка придет к Вам 01.02.2018 года в 13.00 часов, до получения осталось 20 дней 18 часов и "тикает на убывание".

Желательно чтобы, счетчик был на стороне сервера и не зависел от клиента, и на любом сайте время тикало одинако.

Буду благодарна любой помощи.

Comment: *Желательно чтобы, счетчик был на стороне сервера и не зависел от клиента, и на любом сайте время тикало одинако.* Вы понимаете, что на каждый тик потребуется запрос от клиента к серверу и приём ответа? Считайте на клиенте, и с разумной дискретностью (скажем, раз в час) синхронизируйтесь с сервером.

Comment: Вы правы, я об этом не подумала, в интернете много готовых решений с JS, но там все у клиента, для меня это немного но то . Akina, как раз реализовать ваш подход? можно по подробнее)

Comment: А какие тут ещё подробности нужны? Грузится страница, получает время с сервера и начинает его считать локально. Одновременно прикидывает, когда сделать следующий запрос. Если этот момент наступил - запрашивается актуальное время с сервера, оно заменяет текущее... и всё повторяется.

Comment: примерным кодом)

Comment: то есть необходимо запустить счетчик на сервере и возвращать время по запросу джаваскрипта?

Comment: Нет, абсолютно весь код - на клиенте. Сервер только по запросу возвращает текущий остаток времени.